# servlet not found by the browser when it is there

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to handle the form-data and put it in the data base *derbi* that comes with netbeans.The server i am using is *Glassfish*. After filling the form when i click the *submit data* button, according to the action handler the request should follow to a servlet named *FormHandler.do* but when i try to reach out to the page *FormHandler.do* this is the error message displayed by the browser :

```
This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: 
file:///W:/UnderTest/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/src/java/FormHandler/FormHandler.do
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.
```

But the file is there in the same directory as the html file *(that has form)*. This is the type of url i give in the form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="FormHandler.do"> 
<b>Name:</b><input type="text" name="Name" /> <br /> <br />
<b>Email:</b><input type="email" name="Email" /> <br /> <br />
<b>Password:</b><input type="password" name="Password" /> <br /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
```

What could be the reason for this problem ?

[image]

(After the request goes to the servlet *FormHandler.do* it checks *(as per logic)* if the text fields are empty. If they are empty it forwards the request to a servlet that shows the errors and if correct it inserts that data into the database and shows the success servlet.)

Comment: Did you properly register the servlet, either in web.xml or via annotations in FormHandler.java itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No webpage was found for the web address: 
>   file:///W:/UnderTest/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/src/java/FormHandler/FormHandler.do

You need to access web resources by a HTTP path, not by a local disk file system path. Something like as:

> http://localhost:8080/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/FormHandler.do

The `/WebApplication_GLASSFISH` part is the context path. It's unclear which one you're using, but this information is printed in the server's startup log. Something like as this:

```
INFO: WebApplication_GLASSFISH was successfully deployed in 3,770 milliseconds.
```

You need to make sure that the URL in your browser address bar matches this.

Also, HTML files should go in "Web Pages", not in "Source Packages". After you move the `Registration.html` into "Web Pages", you can open it by

> http://localhost:8080/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/Registration.html

This way the form will submit to the proper servlet URL assuming that you've a

```html
<form action="FormHandler.do">
```

This all is rather trivial. I'd suggest to go through a bit decent Servlet book/tutorial once again. Put your mouse above the [servlets](/questions/tagged/servlets) tag which you put below the question and click at the *info* link to get a good starting point.

Comment: Now i get an error of `404`. I have placed registration.html in the Web-Pages directory and have changed the action url to `http://localhost:8080/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/FormHandler.do`

Comment: Perhaps the context path (the `/WebApplication_GLASSFISH` part) is different. You need to read the server logs to which context path the webapp is been deployed. This is by the way configureable in project's properties, but as I don't use Netbeans, I can't tell from top of head where exactly to configure it. At least, it's printed in the server logs. Note that you shouldn't hardcode the full URL in `<form action>`. Just `FormHandler.do` is sufficient if the `Registration.html` is in the same path.

Comment: You need to open the `registration.html` by an URL, not by a disk file system path. How else did you expect your future webpage visitors to open it? As to the 404, this is answered in my previous comment. As to learning servlets, check our servlets wiki page (the page behind the tag *info* link).

Comment: when i open using [http://localhost:8080/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/Registration.html](http://localhost:8080/WebApplication_GLASSFISH/Registration.html) i get error `404`

Comment: As said several times before, check if the context path is right. Please note that URLs are case sensitive. You've "Registration.html" in your screenshot in the current question and you've "registration.html" in the screenshot in your previous comment. What is it? Further, Eclipse offers a "Run on server" option for JSP files which should automatically open it by right URL, doesn't Netbeans offer this? You seem to have worked your way totally around Netbeans by going to file explorer and doubleclicking the HTML file from there. This is wrong. Use the IDE itself to run and open it.